# Adding a number in one column to a date in another in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timedelta

My first python project that didn't print 'Hello World' - so be gentle. Tried answers from similar questions but they don't seem to work.

I'm working with an Excel file, parsing as pandas dataframe.

I have a calculated column that calculates the number of days to later be added to a date. The number of days to add column is done as below, with 'choices' being a list of integers. This seems to work fine.

```
choices = [0,0,925,778,567,608, 638,730]

df['Days_to_add'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

I now want to add this to an existing date column, to return a new column with the new date. So far i've tried this but Jupyter says its depreciated and will return a TypeError in a future version:

```
df["Estimated Start"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Date1"]) + df['Days_to_add']
```

Also tried this:

```
df['Estimated_Start'] = df.Max_Dec_Date + pd.DateOffset(df['Days_to_add'])
```

And something else that told me to use timedelta index, and something else that pointed to timedelta range. I think the problem is something to do with trying to add an integer to a series?

No success with any of it. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date is not TimeDelta, but DateTime,
so the addition should go like this:

```
df["Estimated Start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date1"]) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Days_to_add'], unit='D')
```